# how to update docker in coreos

Tags: docker, coreos

I typed `docker version` into a newly provisioned coreos instant on ec2 and I got this message

```
Client version: 0.6.3
Go version (client): go1.1.2
Git commit (client): b0a49a3
Server version: 0.6.3
Git commit (server): b0a49a3
Go version (server): go1.1.2
Last stable version: 0.7.3, please update docker
```

how do I update docker?

Comment: You should update the image.  If you did not create the image you're using, speak to the folks that made it./

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CoreOS and the tools it ships are updated automatically as new versions come out.

The CoreOS version on the EC2 marketplace is always a few versions behind, but if you wait a few minutes after booting a machine it should execute an auto-update and then be up to date.

If you want to manually run a new docker binary before it is updated in CoreOS, you can download the binary and run a local docker unit file: https://gist.github.com/philips/7555876

Comment: Generally speaking, you should [inline the relevant content from links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/140656) *into* your answer (especially in cases like this, where the link kinda/sorta answers the original question, but needs relatively simple adaptation to be a direct and comprehensive answer to the question). Just a thought! (=

Answer (score 48):

To update CoreOS manually type in your shell:

```
update_engine_client -update
```

Comment: The title of the question is "how to update *docker* in coreos." Using this command will not update the version of docker included with your CoreOS install unless there is a more recent release of CoreOS on the channel that you're on. Have a look at [the CoreOS releases](https://coreos.com/releases/) page in order to ascertain what versions of key container runtimes are included with the various channels.