# Is it possible to update Docker on CoreOS without updating fleet and etcd?

Tags: docker, coreos, etcd

I have blocked automatic updates of CoreOS on my cluster.
I would like to update my CoreOS docker version to 1.5 which exist on the current stable version, however, the fleet version which exist on this CoreOS release has a bug which i can't live with (related to satellite services - file not found)
Is there a way to update only the docker version to 1.5 without updating everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, this is not the policy CoreOS is following.

You can try downloading docker from source and building it but I'm afraid you will be missing some packages.

Or you could try though to run Docker 1.5 in a container on your CoreOS machine and make the available through the host port, a bit like boot2docker on Mac is doing.

In that case, for myself I would go with another system than CoreOS that would allow me more flexibility, with etcd, fleet, systemd and docker versions of my choosing.

EDIT : doing a bit of research I found this :
[how to update docker in coreos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917981/how-to-update-docker-in-coreos?rq=1)
https://gist.github.com/philips/7555876
Which might provide a solution. Still my last statement is still the solution I would go to.

Comment: Thanks Popinou, 
Regarding you suggestion,  Do you know any Linux distro that officially support systemd, etcd, fleet and Docker ?

Comment: You can pretty much install systemd, etcd and fleet anywhere : https://github.com/systemd/systemd, https://github.com/coreos/etcd, https://github.com/coreos/fleet. You might need to install as well the clients etcdctl, systemdctl and fleetctl, that you can also find on github. Then any distro will be fine. Try with Ubuntu, and install Docker from github (https://github.com/docker/docker) not with apt, in order to get the last version.